# Multiple ModificationForms in Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, state-machine, modification-form

i am working on a Sharepoint Server 2007 Statemachine Workflow. Until now i have a few states and an custom Association/InitiationForm which i created with InfoPath 2007.
At the moment i have a Problem with Modification forms. The modification link in the state page of my workflow is shown and leads on click to my InfoPath form. If i click the "Submit" button the form is closed. Everything works fine.
Now i tried to add a second ModificationForm to my workflow. So i created a new InfoPath form and added it in the same way to the workflow as the first one. The workflow has no errors in the building or deploying-process.
But if i now try to click the second Modification link in the state page the form is not shown. Instead of my form the text: "The form has been closed." is shown.

I looked in the central administration and the InfoPath form is know under "Manage form templates". I gave every Modification in the Workflow.xml his own Guid. I used the following ModificationUrl: ModificationUrl="_layouts/ModWrkflIP.aspx"

Does anybody know step by step how to use two or more ModificationForms in my workflow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I found the following Error Message in the Logfile:

"Form load failed with a validation error"

I searched in the web for solutions for this problem and fount this site:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/83264f93-ebe3-49ec-bd6b-95ee02df4d8a/

I had two sceme files and i just schould use one for both forms. So i had to use the same data source. That was all. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your ULS logs for the error message. It will be listed there 100%. The category is "Forms Services" - the logs are located under the 12 hive in LOGS\